# Probability score for Hierarchical classification models

Tags: classification, multilevel-analysis, scoring-rules

We've a hierarchical classification system in place; where each level produces predictions with a probability. Here's how the hierarchy is setup

- Top level: 1 model; ~25 classes
- Level 1: 25 models(=25 top level classes) each with classes anywhere between 10 to 20
- Level 2: 25*20(worst case) models each with classes ranging from 20-40
  and so on until level N.

Where N is the level which predicts the leaf nodes in the hierarchy.

Each of these models are trained & validated independently with their train/validation sets. Now, when we do a prediction, we pass the input through the top level and all the way down to the Level N model.

At each level we pick the class that has the highest probability and move down the tree. I would like to know what is a good way to report the probability of the prediction at the leaf level. Should it be a product of every level's probability or is it more complex than that?

Also, how do I calibrate my final score so that I can use thresholds to drop not-so-confident results.

PS: If you find the language unclear or ambiguous from an academic stand-point, please let me know and I shall clarify.

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing here and why. What is the purpose of this hierarchy and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Objective is to classify documents(which talk about products - like, cellphone, washer & dryer or espresso machine or some baby diaper, etc) into one of the many classes. We've in total >10k classes. There's an inherent hierarchy among the classes in this space and hence, its natural to think about them in a hierarchical fashion. Also, since, not all classes get good enough representation - in terms of ground truth or test set, it's hard to build flat models with high level of precision. It also helps to stop at some level in the hierarchy where we have high confident predictions.